# Django form fields errors not showing in Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, ajaxform

I have a Django form that makes use of the AJAX. The form works as intended. The problem now is that Django form errors are not shown when invalid input is entered. I followed the Django forms API as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_json). Is there a possible way out of this issue?

`main.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#itemForm").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "post/ajax/myURL/",
            data: serializedData,
            success: function (data) {
                if($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") == true){
                    // some codes here
                    $("#itemsTable tbody").prepend(
                        // some codes here
                    )
                    console.log("Checkbox is checked. Modal will not be closed");
                }
                else if($('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked") == false){
                    // some codes here
                    console.log("Checkbox is unchecked. Modal will now be closed");
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorText, data) {
                for (var name in data) {
                    for (var i in data[name]) {
                        $('#ajaxErrorMessage').fadeIn().text(errorText) ;
                    }
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#ajaxErrorMessage').fadeOut("slow");
                }, 5000 );
                console.log(data.message)
                // more console logs here
            }
        })
    });
});
```

`views.py`

```
def create_item(request):
    # request is sent via ajax
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
        data = {}
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save()
            # serialize the new item object in json
            data = serializers.serialize('json', [data, ])
            # send data to the client side
            return JsonResponse({"data": data}, status=200)
        else:
            # raise form errors if there is any
            return JsonResponse(data=form.errors.as_json(escape_html=False), safe=False, status=400)
    form = ItemForm()
    return HttpResponse(data=form.errors.as_json(escape_html=False), safe=False, status=400)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error function of `jQuery.ajax()` only receives three arguments (Reference https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), namely:

> **jqXHR** jqXHR, **String** textStatus, **String** errorThrown

If you want the data returned from the ajax call you need to access it from `jqXHR`:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorText) {
    let data = jqXHR.responseJSON;
    // If above line does not work, might not since you don't specify `dataType: "json"` use below line
    // let data = $.parseJSON($xhr.responseText);
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```